# SVN post-commit hook on Windows stopped running

Tags: svn

I'm running SVN on Windows and had a post-commit hook that was running the day I set it up.   Now it's not running anymore.  I'm running SVN through Apache Httpd.  As part of my troubleshooting, I did the following:

- Successfully checked in a file and viewed it from the TortoiseSVN's repo browser
- Verified that the post-commit.bat file was in the hooks directory of my repository
- Cut down the post-commit.bat file to be this one line:

  `echo hello > hello.txt`
- Checked-in a file and looked for the hello.txt file in the Apache installation folder (E:\Applications\Apache2.2) and its subdirectories, but found nothing
- Verified the Apache service was up and running (which it must have been to have successfully checked in)
- Eyeballed my services using `services.msc` to see if there might be some monitoring service I need running that was stopped accidentally; I didn't recognize any
- I created a pre-commit hook and verified that it is running as expected (so this is only a problem with the post-commit hook -- not all hooks in general)

**What are the next steps I should take to troubleshoot why my post-commit hook is not executing?**

Comment: what do you mean by `Wrote a post-commit.bat file and verified that it IS RUNNING`

Comment: I mean that a made a post-commit hook, and that hook is running as expected.

Comment: Have you checked apache logs? They should tell you what's happening.

Comment: I meant *pre-commit* hook.  That was a typo.  My error.log does not show any activity around my commits.  I see my connections in the access.log, but nothing indicating a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved...**  Sort of.

I restarted the Apache service and everything magically started working.  What should I hate from this experience?  Subversion, Apache, or Windows?

Comment: Not sure, but to be safe... Windows!

Answer (score 0):

It's so simple it's absurd, but did you verify that the user running the script has permissions to write to the working directory?  Often web exposed services don't as your script could effectively rewrite itself (or other scripts).

Comment: I believe so.  It's running under my account, and I'm an administrator on that server.  Am I correct in assuming my working directory is E:\Applications\Apache2.2\bin?  I have full access to that directory.

Comment: Apache often shifts from a system wide superuser to a lesser no-permissions user after binding port 80.  It does this to prevent miswritten CGI and other dynamic content from altering the configuration and content it serves.  I'm not saying this is your case, but it merits enough investigation to determine that it's not part of your issue.